# How to use parameterized queries in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, acc

How to use parameterized queries in vb.net?
Because I always wanted to make a program that could read an ms access database and display results based on your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the desired query using question marks in the place of your parameters

```
Dim sql = "SELECT * FROM Students WHERE Name = ?"
```

Then create a OleDbCommand object and set the appropriate values (CommandText and so on).  Then add Parameters to the command object.
Finally, execute it how you need.  Eg as ExecuteReader.